# objectId in Parse is always NULL

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my Activity I init the [Parse service](https://parse.com):

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());

ParseObject.registerSubclass(Person.class);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Area.class);

Parse.initialize(this, "MY_APP_ID", "MY_CLIENT_KEY");
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

I have this class

```
@ParseClassName("Area")
public class Area extends ParseObject {    
    public static ParseQuery<Area> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Area.class);
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return getString("objectId");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return getString("name");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        put("name", name);
    }
}
```

First I want to retrieve data from the Parse service like this

```
    ParseQuery<Area> areaQuery = Area.getQuery();
    areaQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Area>() {
        public void done(List<Area> areas, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(areas,
                        new SaveCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                //output errors
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                //output errors
            }
        }
    });
```

but the ParseObjects do not have an `objectId`.
Later I want to retrieve data from my local datastore like this

```
ParseQuery<Area> query = Area.getQuery();
query.orderByAscending("name");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Area>() {
    public void done(List<Area> areaList, ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.d("area", "Error retrieving areas");
            return;
        }
        for (Area a : areaList)
            areaResults.add(a);
    }
});
```

That always throws a `ParseException`:

> com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for 'objectId'. Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.

Well because the ParseObjects actually do not have an `objectId`. Neither in my local datastore nor when querying directly from Parse.

What is going wrong here? I took the code from various examples and it should work.

Comment: my be there is no data inside local data store. you have to fetch data from server

Comment: There is data. And if I don't `registerSubclass` I can get the data as decribed in my question.

Comment: Change sequence `initialize` first and then after `enableLocalDatastore`

Comment: @kishorejethava: From the doc: *To enable the datastore, call Parse.enableLocalDatastore() in your Application constructor before calling Parse.initialize()* Otherwise an exception is thrown.

Comment: Does your Area object have an another db object as field?

Comment: @SedatPolat: No. It only has a `name` field besides the default fields.

Comment: Could you post your Area class? I did not get any error like that.

Comment: @SedatPolat: I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You have included a getter for objectId in your subclass. This is already accessible from the parent class and should not overridden.

**Old answer**

The problem is probably that objects in local datastore does not have an objectId *until* it has been saved remotely to Parse. Only then does it get an objectId.

You need to make sure your objects have been saved remotely OR you need to pin objects locally before querying them. In the case of pinning, you cannot access the objectId unless it has also been saved remotely.

Comment: At the beginning I do not have any data in the local datastore. And when hitting sync and requesting data from the cloud, the `objectId` is `null`. That should not happen, right? I looked at 100 times at my code and compared it to the code tutorials. But I don't see the difference.

Comment: Why are you including a getter for objectId in your subclass? This is already accessible from the parent class and should not be overridden.

Comment: Wow. That was it. Since you were the first to notice, you could update your post and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `getString("objectId");`. You must not implement default Parse Column `getters/setters`.

You can get it with `getObjectId()` which has already been implemented in ParseObject. Also  to get `updatedAt`, `createdAt` and some other default Parse column, you have to use their own `Getters` such as `getUpdatedAt()` and `getCreatedAt()`.

At the below, I removed your `objectId` getter implementation. You should implement only your own column fields.

```
@ParseClassName("Area")
public class Area extends ParseObject {    
    public static ParseQuery<Area> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Area.class);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return getString("name");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        put("name", name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your empty constructor or call super() within it.

Comment: Tried it. No difference.

Comment: Try parse initialization within custom application and try again. Everything is working fine from my side. Or may you post full source code.

Comment: *parse initialization within custom application*. What do you mean by that?

Comment: public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Custom.class);
        Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_KEY);
    }
} and in AndroidManifest <application
        android:name=".App" ...>...</application>

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But did not change anything.